# How to run Code after asynchronus code is finished, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, pdfkit

I have a asynchronus Funktion, loadHTMLString, that I call to load the Text out of an HTML File. The loading Process needs time, almost a second. The Problem is: I want to go on with my Code, if the File is loaded, but I dont know when the loading is finished. Is there a way to do that?

```
func generateAndLoadPDF() {
    // Thats my HTML File
    let html = HTML.get(from: "Vorlage.html")
    // I load this HTML File in my WebView, that takes almost a second
    wkWebView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: Bundle.main.bundleURL)
    // I delayed the Following Code, so the HTML-String has time to load
    // Actually I dont want to delay the Code, I want that the following Code runs after .loadHTMLString is finished.
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
        // I generate the PDF
        let wkPDFData = PDF.generate(using: self.wkWebViewPrintFormatter())
        self.loadIntoWKWebView(wkPDFData)
    }
}
```

Thanks,
Boothosh

Answer (score 1):

Conform to `WKNavigationDelegate`

```
webView.navigationDelegate = self
```

---

```
extension ViewController: WKNavigationDelegate {  
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        debugPrint("didFinish")
    } 
}
```

Comment: Sh_Khan told you what to do. Declare yourself as conforming to the `WKNavigationDelegate` protocol. Set yourself as the web view's delegate. (That step is important.) Then, once you've done that, the body of your `webView(_:didFinish:)` method will be called (You would put the code that runs once the web view has loaded inside that function.)

Comment: Jes okay its works, New Problem: With this solution, my Code runs everytime when I change my View. Problem is that its a loop then, because the Code, wich runs, change the View... Is there a Solution to not call this loop?